# Generate Http endpoints using avro rpc like generate interfaces

Tags: java, apache, rpc, avro, idl

Can we generate endpoints using avro idl or avpr files? if possible may i know the procedure. I have generated pojos and interfaces using avroRPC. But unable to generate http endpoints. Can you please suggest right approach to auto generate endpoints using avro rpc?